# not able to pass devise form parameter to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

i am using devise gem and created a name column in user table. but i am not able to pass name parameter to database. i made changes in form what changes i need to do to pass form data into database?

sign_up.html.erb

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
    </div>
```

i am able to pass password and email into database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to whitelist that parameter for devise.

Add this into your `application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

...

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
end
```